# How to split value of one cell into multiple cells in Excel?

Tags: excel, separator

I have `Name and Address` column in excel looks like a

[image: Data]

I want to take City name and Pincode in separate  columns like

```
Secunderabad   500094
warangal       506005
warangal       506005
```

Is it possible to do in excel? or is there any option for this please let me know

Comment: it would require string manipulation using a macro

Comment: I don't know VBA. Please tell me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all are separated with a hyphen, "-", then you could use the `Left` and `Right` functions as follows:

```
=LEFT(A1, FIND("-",A1) - 1)
```

and

```
=RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1) - FIND("-",A1))
```

where A1 is the cell with city and code together, and the `Left` formula gets the city and the `Right` formula gets the code.

EDIT

Assuming each cell has `CITY-` and `PHNO-` to set off the positions of each, then you could do something like the following.

Get city name:

```
=TRIM(MID(A1, FIND("CITY-",A1) + 5, FIND("-", A1, FIND("CITY-",A1) + 5) - FIND("CITY-",A1) - 5))
```

Get code:

```
=TRIM(MID(A1, FIND("-", A1, FIND("CITY-",A1) + 5) + 1, FIND("PHNO-",A1) - FIND("-", A1, FIND("CITY-",A1) + 5) - 1))
```

Get phone number:

```
=RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1) - FIND("PHNO-",A1) - 4)
```

If a cell doesn't contain a `PHNO-` or a `CITY-`, then the formulas will not work.

Comment: ya all are separated by `-` but there is one more `-` for `phno-`

Comment: But if `phno-` is in a different cell, then it doesn't matter. If you have multiple hyphens in the same cell, then you could use the `Mid` function to get the desired result.

Comment: it is going wrong.. when i draging it showing some name along with address.. How to use mid ?

Comment: @Ram Oh, I see, I interpreted each line in your example as a separate cell, but various lines are contained in one cell. Well, what you need to do is, first of all, ensure that you have a separator between address, city, code, and phone number. This separator can be a "-", but then the "-" shouldn't show up in the rest of the string. For example, the "B -5" would cause problems, because splitting the string on "-" would create a separation between the "B" and the "5". Without some sort of structure to the cell value, it is hard or impossible to split accurately.

Comment: @Ram Like I said, there must be some structure to the string value. For example, if there were a hyphen between the address and the city, then we could do it. But in your example there isn't, so we wouldn't know where the address ends and the city name begins. Or there could be something like `PHNO-`, such as `CITY-` to set off where the city begins, but there must be something.

Comment: @Ram Is the city and code always on its own line within the cell (using Alt-Enter)? If so, I think we could do it.

Comment: Nothing happening while pressing Alt+Enter